# Is there a good package/library to add Pagination/Sorting/Searching to my table? ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor

I am new to web development in ASP.NET Core. I have a table with information, I would like to add pagination/sorting/searching to the table. Is there an easy way to add this using some sort of library/package? Thanks

[image]

I need pagination, sorting, and searching for my ASP.NET Core table.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add pagination/sorting/searching to the table. Is
> there an easy way to add this using some sort of library/package?

Well, considering all the requirement you can go for `jquery data table` regardless of simplicity, quick implementation and free subscription. Importantly, its light weight and easy to use.

Here is the compplete example how you can implement that:

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ConAction()
    {
        var controlleractionlist = _context.Controller.ToList();
        return Json(controlleractionlist);
    }
```

**Note:** I am returning a simple list to demonstrate you , sorting, searching and paging functionality.

**View:**

```
<table id="userTable_info" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>action </th>
            <th>controller </th>
            <th>returnType</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tBody"> </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts {

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Button Click Functions
        function DetailsFunc(data) {
            alert("User Id:" + data + " Details!");
        }
        function EditFunc(data) {
            alert("User Id:" + data + " will be Edited!");
        }
        function DeleteFunc(data) {
            alert("User Id:" + data + " will be deleted!");
        }
        //On Load
        $(document).ready(function () {

           
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost:5094/Home/ConAction',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var id = 0;
                    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                        id++;
                        console.log(id);
                        var tr = "<tr>";
                        tr += "<td>" + value.action + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + value.controller + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + value.returnType + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + "<input type='button' id='" + id + "'  class='btn btn-info' onclick='DetailsFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Details'>" + "  " + "<input type='button' id='" + value.id + "'  class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Edit'>" + "  " + "<input type='button' id='" + value.id + "'  class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteFunc(" + value.id + ")' value='Delete'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";

                        $("#tBody").append(tr);
                    });
                    $("#userTable_info").DataTable();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

You could refer to [`official document for more details`](https://datatables.net/).